# Arduino buzzer music expected '}' before numeric constant

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to create Arduino buzzer controller, to play music, but when I was defining H (half) for a duration of notes, it is giving me errors

> sketch_jan30g:24:11: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
>
> #define H 2*Q //half 2/4
>
> ```
>        ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\koumakpet\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_955882\sketch_jan30g.ino:49:3:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'H'
>
> H+Q, Q, Q
>
> ^
>
> sketch_jan30g:24:11: error: expected ',' or ';' before numeric
>   constant
>
> #define H 2*Q //half 2/4
>
> ```
>        ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\koumakpet\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_955882\sketch_jan30g.ino:49:3:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'H'
>
> H+Q, Q, Q
>
> ^
>
> sketch_jan30g:57:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> exit status 1 expected '}' before numeric constant

I'm not sure, what is the mistake, code:

```
//*****************************************
#define B3  247
#define C4  262   //Defining note frequency
#define D4  294
#define E4  330
#define F4  349
#define G4  392
#define LA4  440
#define B4  494
#define Bb4 466
#define C5  523
#define D5  587
#define E5  659
#define F5  698
#define G5  784
#define LA5  880
#define B5  988

// DURATION OF THE NOTES 
#define BPM 120    //  you can change this value changing all the others
#define H 2*Q //half 2/4
#define Q 60000/BPM //quarter 1/4 
#define E Q/2   //eighth 1/8
#define S Q/4 // sixteenth 1/16
#define W 4*Q // whole 4/4
//*****************************************
int notes[] = {       //Note of the song, 0 is a rest/pulse
   E4, C5, E5,
   D5, F5, G5,
   E5,
   0, Bb4, F5, G5, LA5, F5,
   E5, E5, C5, E5,
   B4, 0,

   E4, C5, E5,
   D5, F5, G5,
   E5,
   0, Bb4, F5, G5, LA5, F5,
   E5, E5, C5, E5,
   B4, 0,
   0
};
//*****************************************
int duration[] = { 
  H+Q, Q, Q
  H+Q, Q, Q
  W,
  Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q,
  H, H
  H, Q, Q, Q,
  W+H+Q, Q,
  3*W

};

void setup() {
  for (int i=0;i<203;i++){              //203 is the total number of music notes in the song
  int wait = duration[i];
  tone(buzzer,notes[i],wait);          //tone(pin,frequency,duration)
  delay(wait);}                        //delay is used so it doesn't go to the next loop before tone is finished playing
  //You can click reset on Arduino to replay the song
}

void loop() {

}
```

EDIT:
Note that I've tried replacing the positions of H and Q (because H is dependant on Q), the error was still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
int duration[] = { 
  H+Q, Q, Q
  H+Q, Q, Q
  W,
  Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q,
  H, H
  H, Q, Q, Q,
  W+H+Q, Q,
  3*W
};
```

you are missing commas at the end of the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I played with macro expansions, but try switching places on your definition of H and definition of Q. It might be that H isn't being expanded properly since it relies on Q.